# How to change months with Datepicker

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there any way to change the date (value returned by getDate) pressing the change month arrows without using setDate?

Answer (score 0):

It's not much clear your request..try to specify better; anyway see the documentation about datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a function of datepicker that returns the month in which you are without clicking a number just moving using arrows (ui-datepicker-prev / next).

I looked in the documentation and I don't find it, although I imagine it exists. Now I'm using setDate but it's not cool.
I only want a link.